# how can I set an anchor point on a div class or id

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I set anchor point at about-us class?

This is the html

```
<div class="about-us" id="about-us">
    <div class="container center con-about-us">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Aproape de <span>dumneavoastra</span></h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Salty Spa este locul ideal în care va oferim posibilitatea de a va relaxa si de a avea grija de sanatate prin intermediul<br>
            terapiei saline in orasul dumneavoastra. Intr-o atmosfera placuta si un cadru ambiant amenajat corespunzator<br>
            pentru a va simtii rasfatati, beneficiind de servicii de inalta calitate.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.about-us {
    background-color:#f2f2f2;   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;  
}

.about-us span {color: #333;}
.about-us p {font-weight: 300;font-size: 15px;color:#a5a5a5;}
```

I want when the scroll reach the about-us class to put a animation.
I use https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Do you mean a **trigger** point? You would need Javascript to do that.

Comment: Yes. It's ok with java. But I don't know to make that script..

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
var aboutUSOffset = $(".about-us").offset().top;
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

   if (offset >= aboutUSOffset) {
     //do animation script
   }
```

});